# How is the notion of minimising potential energy consistent with a magnets behaviour when placed in an external magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

If isolated systems always settle in states of minimum potential energy and $U=-\mu \cdot B$, for a magnet with magnetic moment $\mu$ in an external magnetic field $B$. It should be the case that that the magnetic moment will tend towards aligning with the $B$ field, to have the most negative energy in a sense. But for the case where the magnetic moment is in anti alignment with the field, $U$ is maxamised, yet there is no turning force on the magnetic moment which will try to act and bring its magnetic moment in alignment with the field.

It seems that both the aligned and anti aligned states are stable equilibriums, how is this consistent with the notion of systems favouring states of minimum potential energy?

Comment: The anti-alligned form is in fact an unstable equilibrium. If you calculate the force when you turn an anti-alligned dipole, you will clearly see that it is not a restoring force but a force which would try to take away the dipole from the anti-alligned position.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the idea of equilibrium with stability. A state of equilibrium can be stable or unstable.

Mechanical equilibrium is when the net force on a particular object is zero. In both aligned and antialinged magnetic moments you have equilibrium since, as you correctly stated, there is no torque acting on the magnet (a.k.a. no force trying to move it).

Stability has to do with the forces that might appear when the system is slightly displaced from its state of equilibrium (not in the state of equilibirum itself since by definition there are no forces acting on it in that situation). When the magnet is aligned with the external field and you rotate it a small angle from this alignement (equilibirum) position a force will appear that would point towards the equilibrium configuration, thus restoring the aligned state whenever it can. In the antialigned state this is reversed, when you move the magnet a small angle a force will appear away from the equilibrium position and the magnet would catastrophically turn until it reaches the aligned equilibrium.

To make it more mathematical: you need to remembernot only the formula for the energy $U = -\vec{\mu}\cdot \vec{B}$ but also the formula that tells you what torque the system is experiencing $\vec{\tau} = \vec{\mu} \times \vec{B}$. With the use of the right hand rule you can see that the magnet will rotate towards the aligned situation both from slight deviations from the aligned and antialigned situations and there is no situation were you would see a torque trying to rotate the magnet towards the antialined position. Thus even if both aligned and antialigned are equilibirum states of the system one is stable and the other is absolutely unstable.

The fact that the antialigned configuration is an unstable equilibirum does not mean that the system can't be in that state for ever. Ideally this could happen just as ideally you could have a pencil perfectly balanced on its tip. So the minimum energy is not reached by any "Law" of mechanics really, the maximum energy in this case is perfectly fine as a constant state as long as we ignore any other effects. The idea of minimizing energy in nature is more a "tendency" of nature built upon the second Law of thermodynamics. Any change in your system (even if subatomical in scale) will make the magnet turn to align itself with the field, and since absolute zero is unreachable the magnet will always be embeded in a thermal bath with atoms and molecules bouncing and randomly making slight displacements on the magnet. Also ideally the magnet would "fall" from the antialigned situation to the aligned one but will surpass the equilibirum position (because of inertia) and would start to swing like a pendulum around this position, but again the second Law of thermodynamics would guarantee that the energy of this system will dissipate over time (as heat produced by friction of the swinging magnet with the air, or just as electromagnetic waves radiating away because of the perturbance of the overall magnetic field by means of this swinging). In turn in nature the magnet will always fall towards alignment and stabilize itself in that configuration; that's why we usually think in terms of a tendency towards minimum energy, but remember, there is no law in nature forcing you to go to minimum energy, and in classical mechanics ideal systems can be found in unstable equilibria at rest.